# Excel - How to return a list of values in one column if a value in another column meets certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

Hello need a bit of excel help here if possible

i have a list of prices in column a in ascending order and certain price thresholds (min/max) in 2 different cells in column b. I'm trying to pull all prices that lie within the two price thresholds into a third column, column c, but with no empty cells in between.

for example: if the thresholds are set at £20 (minimum) and £30 (maximum) i want to pull all prices that lie within £20 and £30 in column a into column   c

would anyone be able to help with this problem? it would be much appreciated

Comment: You can use `Vlookup()` I believe. Can you post a table with some sample data?

Comment: column a has prices from £19 to £52, all integers only

Comment: the thresholds are £24 minimum and £39 maximum.

Comment: Actually, it may be easier. Can you just Sort by Value, then filter out those that aren't in the threshold?

Answer (score 0):

I know there's probably a more elegant solution but this would get you where you want to go, I think.

[TableSortImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLVNU.jpg)